# If you escape Zarya's ultimate, is it possible to get caught in it again?

Tags: overwatch

There are a few heroes who are able to escape Zarya's Graviton Surge ultimate after being caught in it, including Reinhardt (through Charge) and Reaper (through Wraith Form).

If I escape Zarya's ultimate using one of these characters, is it possible to get caught in the ultimate again if I get too close?

Comment: It *is* a gravitational surge, so it would make sense that if you don't escape it area of effect that it would pull you back in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can easily test this by Blinking just once as Tracer, it won't move you out of the area of effect and you'll quickly be caught again.

Comment: Certain abilities like Winston's leap do not have sufficient momentum to escape in the first place. I also have trouble escaping if I'm near the epicentre as Pharah.

Comment: @KizTrap Nitpicking, but epicenter is not the correct word in this context. Just center is fine.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Since you enjoy nitpicking, here's the second [definition of epicenter](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/epicenter) from the Free Dictionary: " The focal point of a usually harmful or unpleasant phenomenon or event; the center:". So that's perfect.

Comment: @DCShannon But that's only used in metaphors, not in actual physical events like a Graviton Surge.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I don't know what gives you that idea, nor do I feel like debating it. That was a perfectly good use of the word that fits with a common definition. I just want to caution you against randomly criticizing people's word choices without anything to back it up.

Comment: @DCShannon "Epicenter is properly a geological term identifying the point of the earth's surface directly above the focus of an earthquake. No doubt this is why the Usage Panel approves of **figurative extensions of its use in dangerous, destructive, or negative contexts**." From what you linked. I don't see what's wrong with correcting people when they're wrong, but this is getting way off topic now.